# What's the best HTML5 element to contain a set of figures?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I want to have a set of 1 or more (probably no more than 10) `<figure>` elements in a carousel. Since I want these to fill their parent element, I don't think putting them in `<li>`s in an `<ol>` or a `<ul>` will be the best choice. I considered a `<section>` but that seems to not exactly fit the description of "a set of figures". **What, if any, HTML5 semantic element(s) would be the best to contain *only* several related `<figure>`s as direct children?**

This will be used as an unstyled, general, universally-useful carousel. Because of that, each figure in the carousel will contain similar, but distinct content. Examples might include information about an organization, slideshow of photos from a trip, quotes about a product, recent posts to a news site, etc.

Comment: It depends on the purpose of the figures (carousel about what?), their context on the page (the carousel is part of …?), and the outline of the whole document (how is the page in question structured?).

Comment: @unor I hope not, because I'm trying to make a generic system that anyone can use on any page. I assume all items in the carousel will have a subject, and optional info about the subject. That seems to fit the generic description of figures well enough, but I don't know what to contain them in.

Comment: So users may put this carousel *anywhere* on a page (as part of the main content, in a sidebar about related information, in the site header, etc.)? Then this would be similar to asking: *What would be the best element to contain `blockquote` elements?* -- there really can’t be a general answer. -- Are all the `figure` elements necessarily about the same subject, or could they be about totally different topics (e.g., a few containing teasers for blog posts, a few containing recent photographs, one about the site mission, etc.)?

Comment: Correct, this would be a similar question to _What would be the best element to contain **a set of** blockquote elements?_, in that, it's a list of items, but not a `ul`, `ol`, or `menu`. All the `figure`s will likely be similar items illustrating the same or similar topic (information about an organization, slideshow of photos from a trip, quotes about a product, recent posts to a news site, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since I want these to fill their parent element, I don't think putting them in `<li>`s in an `<ol>` or a `<ul>` will be the best choice.

I don't see how that follows. It seems to me that this is a list of figures, so those are the normal choices. "Filling a parent element" I would take to refer to the visual appearance, and there's no reason why a list might not have that appearance.

If you really want to directly contain the element then considering you say:

> unstyled, general, universally-useful

That'd be `<div>`.

If another elements fits a given purpose better than `<div>` then you should go for it, but `<div>`'s value is precisely in its semantic weakness; in not matching any meaning well enough to say anything, it says nothing and so doesn't match any meaning so well as to say the wrong thing.

It also means that you can use it inside a `<section>`, `<aside>` or something else if that fits a better use. (Or perhaps define your reuse mechanism in such a way as to allow such an element to be used, with `<div>` as the default).

But it still sounds like a list rendered as a carousel to me, from the rest of your description.

Comment: It's difficult to get `Element A`'s child's child to fill `Element A` (or, `UL > LI > FIGURE`). It's much easier and more reliable to just have its direct children fill it.

Comment: I think that difficulty is more related to animating a carousel rather than from the markup.  You have a list of figures; use a list.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple div is a good idea to begin

Comment: Why's that? The W3C says "When no other element is suitable, the <div> element is used as an element of last resort. Otherwise, it leads to poor accessibility for reader."